# Remove Duplicate Edges In Graph Data Structure

Tags: c, graph

I  have this current Graph Datastructure read into memory.

```
struct Edge
{
    char s; // source
    char d; // destination
    int w; // weight
};

struct Graph
{
    int v; //number of vertices
    int e; //number of edges
    struct Edge* edge;
};
```

After reading in my graph, these are the following components :

```
<A, B, 2> <A, F, 9> <A, G, 5> <B, A, 2> <B, C, 4> <B, G, 6> <C, B, 4> <C, D, 2> <C, H, 5> <D, C, 2> <D, E, 1> <D, H, 1> <E, D, 1> <E, F, 6> <E, I, 3> <F, A, 9> <F, E, 6> <F, I, 1> <G, A, 5> <G, B, 6> <G, H, 5> <G, I, 2> <H, C, 5> <H, D, 1> <H, G, 5> <H, I, 4> <I, E, 3> <I, F, 1> <I, G, 2> <I, H, 4>
```

However, because this graph is symmetrical, I need only half the edges because there are duplicates.

How can I delete multiple edges?

For instance, I know [A, B, 2] and [B, A, 2] are the same edge. I can remove [B,A,2].

Below is code that I thought would work but doesn't :

```
int remove_dups(struct Graph * graph1, struct Graph * graph)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;

for(i; i < N; i++)
{
    for(j; j < N; j++)
    {
        if(graph->edge[i].s == graph1->edge[j].d || graph->edge[i].d == graph1->edge[j].s)
            free(graph1->edge[i]);
    }
 } 
}
```

Where should I start by doing this? I know my graph has 15 edges because 30 / 2 = 15. So I have twice as many edges as I need because I have duplicates. Any help would be nice. This is my first post. Thank you

Comment: C or C++? The solutions will differ fundamentally.

Comment: I think Your `j` variable needs to be reinitialized (to `j = i + 1`) for every `i`.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate question. But very similar premise! https://stackoverflow.com/q/56436642/14065

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. It is C

Comment: How have You allocated `graph1->edge`? I suspect that `free()` may be a problem - I guess You haven't allocated every single edge, but You are trying to free it.

Comment: Yes I've allocated for it. I guess I'm more wondering if the approach I choose is correct for finding the duplicate edges.

Comment: Your approach would be correct with `for (i=0; i<N-1; i++) ... for (j=i+1; j<N; j++)`. And with correct deallocation and skipping already deallocated edges in the loop.

Comment: Your code attempts to free a duplicate edge. There are two problems with this. One, the code you show suggests `graph-edge` is an array of edges, in which case you cannot free individual elements of it. It was allocated as an entire array and can only be freed as an entire array. Two, you need to remove the edge from the array (or other data structure), not just release the memory it uses. One way to solve both of these would be, when a duplicate is found, copy the last array element over the duplicate and then use `realloc` to shrink the array.

Comment: Note that, when using `realloc` to shrink the array, you must update the pointer or pointer(s) to it. (In particular, `graph->edge` must be changed.) It may be preferable to keep track of where the end of the array is while processing all of the edges (if `N` is the number of edges, it decreases when you remove an edge) and then call `realloc` just once after all of the duplicates have been handled. Also notice that, if you write over a duplicate, you cannot let `i` and `j` increment immediately. You have to check if the new edge in the current location is also a duplicate.

Comment: It is odd that `remove_dups` is passed two pointers to a graph. If it is only removing duplicate edges from one graph, it only needs one pointer.

Comment: Okay I will try that approach. Thank you!

Comment: Consider whether you actually want to deduplicate at all.  It will save you some memory for graph storage, but you will need to account for the two possible vertex orders in all your code that analyzes the resulting graphs.  Note also that you should be careful to distinguish between an undirected graph and a directed one in which each edge is matched with one going the opposite direction.  Deduplicating makes more sense to me for the former than for the latter.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as time as he says `graph is symmetrical` , that means it's undirected.

Comment: Well, @alinsoar, that *could be* what he means, but as I already noted, he could also mean that his graph is directed, with each edge having another going in the opposite direction between the same pair of vertices.  That is *not* the same thing, and it's important (for them) to understand which they are working with.  The difference is whether "symmetrical" describes a property of the graph itself, or whether it describes a property of a particular *representation* of the graph.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok, correct